# What is SSTable overlap in TWCS in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to understand SStable overlaps in cassandra which is not suitable for TWCS. I found references like https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/12/08/TWCS-part1.html but I still don't understand what overlap means and how it is caused by read repairs. Can anyone please provide a simple example that would help me to understand? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TWCS, data is compacted into "time windows". If you've configured a time window of 1 hour, TWCS will compact (combine) all partitions written within a one-hour window into a single SSTable. Over a 24-hour period you will end up with 24 SSTables, one for each hour of the day.

Let's say you inspect the SSTable generated at 9am. The minimum and maximum [write] timestamps in that SSTable would be between 8am and 9am.

Now consider a scenario where a replica has missed a few mutations (writes) around 10am. All the writes between 10am and 11am will get compacted to one SSTable. If a repair runs at 3pm, the missed mutations from earlier in that day will get included in the 3pm to 4pm time-window even when it really belongs to the SSTable from the 10-11am time-window.

In TWCS, SSTables from different time windows will not get compacted together. This means that the data from 2 different time windows is fragmented across 2 SSTables. Even if the 11am SSTable is expired, it cannot be dropped (deleted) from disk because there is data in the 4pm SSTable that overlaps with it. The 11am SSTable will not get dropped until all the data in the 4pm SSTable has also expired.

There's a simplified explanation of how TWCS works in [How data is maintained in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataMaintain.html#dmlHowDataMaintain__twcs). It includes a nice diagram which would hopefully make it easier for you to visualise how data could possibly overlap across SSTables. Cheers!